# Raspberry Pi - sending data using mobile data to closed wifi

Tags: pi-2

I would like to know if we can manipulate a closed wifi network of a drone. I would like to send data from my phone over the internet to the RPI through mobile data which will send the data to the closed wifi network. Is it possible? If yes how?

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi can (on some models only with extra dongles) act as

- [WiFi Client](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md)
- [WiFi Hotspot](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/overview)
- [WiFi to 3G bridge](http://www.g7smy.co.uk/2014/08/raspberry-pi-as-a-3g4g-router/)

So the answer is **yes**.